# File Name form NSFileHandle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, file-io, nsfilehandle

I am using an third party SDK for file handling, they have given some handles for file open, file read, file write. When i create the object of wrapper of that SDK using file path its calls those handle methods (File open, file read etc.).

I want to change the data of file at the time of reading it. But the SDK open multiple supporting files so i am not able to find is it my file in read state or some other file.

They have provided the object of NSFileHandle in there read method is there is any way i can find out is it my file or supporting file using file handle object or is there is any other way around.

Please suggest me the solutions.

Regards:

Comment: How do you open your file? There should be a unique file name/path to it.

Comment: At the time of opening a file i use methos of NSFileHandle.
NSFileHandle *handle;
   if ((mode & SecureFs_FileMode_ReadOnly) != 0)
    {
        handle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:stringPath] retain];
    }
    else if ((mode & SecureFs_FileMode_WriteOnly) != 0)
    {
        handle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:stringPath] retain];
    }
    else if ((mode & SecureFs_FileMode_ReadWrite) != 0)
    {
        handle = [[NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:stringPath] retain];
    }
The file name is provided at the time of creating the object of SDK wrapper.

Comment: Hi @Nilesh, id you get this resolved?